# jquery AJAX Autocomplete fail to append

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have simple jquery autocomplete functionality that gets Json result from service and i want to show returned results with autocomplete but nothing happens. Really don't know how to fix this although it seems simple

```
 <body>

<label for="txtSearch">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="txtSearch"/>
 <div id="results"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: rez,
            appendTo: "#results"
        });
    });

    var rez = function search2() {
        if ($("#txtSearch").val().length > 2) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "Search.aspx/GetCity",
                data: "{'cityName':'" + $("#txtSearch").val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(result.d);
                    return obj;
                }
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: log the `obj` and show result. it may not be needed.

Comment: This is what i get as response, I can show it in alert but when returned to autocomplete it does nothing


[{"ID":"377020","CityName":"Lon","Country":"Spain","Region":"Europe"},{"ID":"114927","CityName":"Lonaconing","Country":"Maryland","Region":"Americas"},{"ID":"375281","CityName":"Lonand","Country":"India","Region":"Asia"},{"ID":"74190","CityName":"Lonate Ceppino","Country":"Italy","Region":"Europe"},{"ID":"419873","CityName":"Lonate Pozzolo","Country":"Italy","Region":"Europe"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery handles the JSON parsing for you. There's no need to send it as a string or to parse the result afterwards if your dataType is "json".

The specific problem you have is that your `rez` function does not have the required arguments passed to it, `request` and `response`. `request` is an object that has properties relating to the search term eg. `request.term`. `response` is a callback function you need to call inside your `$.ajax` success function to pass the data back to autocomplete.

You still needed to parse the data you were getting back from the server though as autocomplete expects either a simple array of values or an array of objects containing the keys `label` and `value` eg:

```
[
    { label: 'London, England', value: 'LDN' },
    { label: 'Liverpool England', value: 'LPL' }
]
```

Use `console.log()` to look at the values you are getting and make they are what you expect/need.

The documentation has an example you can follow here http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: rez,
        appendTo: "#results",
        minLength: 2 // this will check the input is at least 2
    });
});

// request is the search request object,
// response is the callback to pass data back to autocomplete
var rez = function search2( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Search.aspx/GetCity",
        data: { cityName: request.term },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            // results have to be returned via the response callback as 
            // label/value pairs or just an array of values
            response( $.map( result, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: [ item.CityName, item.Country, item.Region].join( ', ' ),
                    value: item.ID
                };
            } ) );
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work either. Function finishes but nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, you should follow the examples in the jQuery UI documentation. The plugin expects the response to be formatted in a specific way and it has to be passed to a callback function. I've updated my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Thank you for you efforts but I can't fix this for days now.

In the meantime I managed this to work but only with variable that hold my response as thext. And now with your updated answer it is the same.

The service is being called and it returns response (looks valid) but nothing happens. I have checked the response and even put it in JS variable and then everything works fine but if I use direct call instead of Json var then no results are being shown. 

I don't know what part could be wrong here? I am using ASP.NET

Comment: What version of jquery and jqueryui are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                label: item.CityName,
                value: item.ID
                }
            }));
        }
```

REFERENCE

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp